# sudo apt-get --install-suggests install git fails

Tags: apt, package-management, git, runit

When I try to install git along with its suggested packages, I get errors indicating that git-daemon-run and runit failed to install properly. Looking up the error messages leads me to https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/runit/+bug/1448164 .

However, this bug thread does not seem to offer very good solutions or workarounds.

Note that I originally ran into this on Ubuntu 15.10, running under VirtualBox. However, I believe 15.04 and 16.04 LTS are also affected.

Answer (score 1):

Install git-daemon-sysvinit first:

```
sudo apt-get install git-daemon-sysvinit
```

If you look at the package properties in Synaptic, you will see that git-daemon-sysvinit can be used instead of git-daemon-run. And unlike the latter, git-daemon-sysvinit actually works on Ubuntu 15.04 and up.

Once you have git-daemon-sysvinit installed, you can run

```
sudo apt-get --install-suggests install git
```

if you want to. However, note that you may not actually need some of these suggested packages. And git itself gets installed automatically when you install git-daemon-sysvinit.